# Scala forward reference of nested recursive function

Tags: scala, recursion, forward-reference

I have this really simple method definition with a nested recursive function:

```
def bar(arr : Array[Int]) : Int = {
  val foo : Int => Int = (i: Int) => if(i == 0) 0 else i + foo(i-1)
  foo(3)
}
```

But I get this error:

```
<console>:36: error: forward reference extends over definition of value foo
     val foo : Int => Int = (i: Int) => if(i == 0) 0 else i + foo(i-1)
                                                              ^
```

If I just put the val foo: ... = ... line by itself, and not nested within a def, everything works

Comment: Why don't you make it a def?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it a `lazy val`:

```
def bar(arr : Array[Int]) : Int = {
  lazy val foo : Int => Int = (i: Int) => if(i == 0) 0 else i + foo(i-1)
  foo(3)
}
```

or a `def`:

```
def bar(arr : Array[Int]) : Int = {
  def foo(i: Int): Int = if(i == 0) 0 else i + foo(i-1)
  foo(3)
}
```

When you

> put the val foo: ... = ... line by itself, and not nested within a def

it becomes a combination of a field and a getter method, and `foo(i-1)` actually calls the getter method instead of referring to the *value* you are defining, which is illegal; but when you have a `val` inside a method, it's just a local variable and doesn't have a getter method.